# LibGDX - Your Android SDK path doesn't contain an SDK! Please install the Android SDK, including all platforms and build tools

Tags: java, android-sdk, libgdx

Ошибка libgdx, выскакивающая, при попытке генерации android проекта. Вроде я установил всевозможные версии android и всевозможные tools, но ошибка всё ещё вылазиет. Что мне нужно сделать? 
[image]
  [image: libgdx error][image: path][image: tools и версии android так же полностью скачаны]

Comment: `Your Android SDK path doesn't contain an SDK! Please install the Android SDK, including all platforms and build tools` Ваш Андройд SDK не содержит SDK. Нижайше просим Вас, пожалуйста, будьте так любезны, не могли бы вы установить Android SDK всключающего все платформы и инструменты сборки проектов

Comment: в Android Studio во вкладке sdk platforms  установлены какие либо api?

Comment: Во вкладке platforms скачаны все android sdk

Comment: Проекта как такового несуществует, так как его не получается сгенерировать из-за ошибки "Your Android SDK..."

Comment: на скриншоте из студии отсутствует строка: android SDK tools, обычно [она под строкой](https://www.fandroid.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Snimok-ekrana-ot-2017-02-07-21-10-52.png) android SDK platform-tools, но у вас отсутствует вовсе. почему так произошло сказать я не могу, возможно установка всего android SDK заново решит проблему.

Comment: На скриншоте, что Вы прислали, я не вижу существенных отличий и присутствие вкладки, которая, по Вашим словам, отсутсвует у меня.

Comment: Так же попытка переустановки SDK не решила проблему

Comment: странно, что вы не видите существенных отличий, когда на вашем скриншоте отсутствуют android SDK tools, о чем вам и пишут в ошибке. Это не вкладка, а пункт в вкладке SDK tools ( то что в столбце name идёт с галочками)

Comment: Теперь я понял о чём Вы. Но как Вы можете заметить, в моей версии android studio отсутствует возможность скачивания этих элементов. (Не знаю, с чем это могло бы быть связано. Возможно с пунктом hide...)

Answer (score 1):

Для работы нужно скачать SDK tools, которые отсутсвуют на фото, благодаря флажочку напротив Hide Obsolete Packages